# Javascript: Mapping two arrays based on indexes then assign the same value for entries that are out of index

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, reduce

I have a function that will give the following result;

```
const points = [10,5,2];

const data = 
[{name:"John",ranking:1},{name:"Sally",ranking:2},{name:"Tom",ranking:3},
{name:"Harry",ranking:4},{name:"Jess",ranking:5},{name:"Kelly",ranking:6}];

const result = data.reduce((result,{name,rank} => 
(result[name]=points[rank-1],result),{});

console.log(result);

{"John": 10,"Sally": 5,"Tom": 2,"Harry": undefined, "Jess": undefined ,"Kelly": undefined}
```

Instead of being undefined, I want all the players that ranked 3rd or onwards being awarded the last value of the array `points` which is 2, how can I modify the function to achieve the following result? Thanks!

```
{"John": 10,"Sally": 5,"Tom": 2,"Harry": 2,"Jess": 2,"Kelly": 2}
```

Comment: Do you mean `Math.min(rank, points.length) - 1` in your index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using `reduce` for such stuff is appropriate.
Would you be ok with an array of objects containing each player and the assigned points?

```
const result = data.map((user) => ({
  ...user,
  points: points[user.ranking-1] || points[points.length-1]
}))
```

Comment: Thanks that works, may I know what the ... in front of user does? I am still very new to Javascript.

Comment: @yhshj https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
Check what happens if it's not there :D Play around with it